# How to join a table without any common field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Below are the tables I'm working on,

**tableA**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║  REVLIMIT    ║ REV  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 8500         ║  69  ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

**tableB**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦ 
║ KID║   Model      ║  
╠════╬══════════════╬ 
║  1 ║ 43453453345  ║  
║  2 ║ 23423423     ║  
║  2 ║ 5566533      ║  
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

I need to join table with table B so that I get the below result

**tableC**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  Model       ║ REV  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 43453453345  ║  69  ║
║  1 ║ 2433423423   ║  69  ║
║  2 ║ 5566533      ║  69  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

ie all the Model in **tableB** should have **REV** as **69** in this case.

I can use only plain MySQL query,How to accomplish that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: where did the second `KID = 1, Model = 2433423423` row come from? There's nothing like that in either table.

Comment: @AafreenFirdaus I think you removed the wrong row in tableC.

Comment: The question you have is a Bad idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT B.KID,B.Model,A.REV
FROM TableA A CROSS JOIN
     TableB B
```

**OR** simply,

```
SELECT B.KID,B.Model,A.REV
FROM TableA A ,TableB B
```

Result:

```
KID Model       REV
--------------------
1   43453453345 69
2   23423423    69
2   5566533     69
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccc0c/2).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
select * from A join b on 1=1
```